# Shrine with Rails multiple polymorphic image uploads

Tags: image-uploading, ruby-on-rails-5, shrine

I've been struggling for about 5 hours trying to understand why Shrine is blocking my uploads. I either get errors like "Shrine: Invalid file", or "Expected Array but got string" in strong params. If there aren't errors, the images aren't actually saved.

```
require "image_processing/mini_magick"

class ImageUploader < Shrine
  include ImageProcessing::MiniMagick

  plugin :activerecord
  plugin :backgrounding
  plugin :cached_attachment_data
  plugin :determine_mime_type
  plugin :delete_raw
  plugin :direct_upload
  plugin :logging, logger: Rails.logger
  plugin :processing
  plugin :remove_attachment
  plugin :store_dimensions
  plugin :validation_helpers
  plugin :versions

  Attacher.validate do
    validate_max_size 2.megabytes, message: 'is too large (max is 2 MB)'
    validate_mime_type_inclusion ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']
  end

  def process(io, context)
    case context[:phase]
    when :store
      thumb = resize_to_limit!(io.download, 200, 200)
      { original: io, thumb: thumb }
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ImageUploader[:image]
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

---

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :images, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy    
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, allow_destroy: true
...
```

---

```
# Strong Params: 

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(
    :name, :brand_id, :category_id, :price, :compare_price, :description,
    images_attributes: { image: [] },
    product_properties_attributes: [:id, :property_id, :value]
  )
...
```

And my view:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :images do |image_form| %>
    <%= image_form.file_field :image, multiple: true %>
  <% end %>
```

According to everything I've read on the docs or from gorails, this should work.  Do I need to restructure the `images_attributes` hash? I also tried using direct_uploads, but struggled to get the presigned_url to work with S3.

Refile makes this really easy, so I'll probably run crying back to that.

Is there something I'm obviously doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [`fields_for` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-fields_for-label-One-to-many), the provided block will be called for each image in the `project.images` collection. So if your product currently doesn't have any images, the block won't be called (according to the docs).

For nested attributes to work, you need to forward the following parameters when creating the Product:

```
product[images_attributes][0][image] = <file object or data hash>
product[images_attributes][1][image] = <file object or data hash>
product[images_attributes][2][image] = <file object or data hash>
...
```

If you look at the "[Multiple Files](http://shrinerb.com/rdoc/files/doc/multiple_files_md.html)" Shrine guide, it's recommended that you just have a single file field which accepts multiple files:

```
<input type="file" name="file" multiple>
```

And then setup direct uploads for this field using [Uppy](https://uppy.io), dynamically generating the `image` field for each uploaded file populated with the uploaded file data hash:

```
<input type="hidden" name="product[images_attributes][0][image]" value='{"id":"...","storage":"cache","metadata":{...}}'>
<input type="hidden" name="product[images_attributes][1][image]" value='{"id":"...","storage":"cache","metadata":{...}}'>
....
```

Alternatively you can just let users attach multiple files, which are all submitted to the app, and then destructure them in the controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    images_attributes = params["files"].map { |file| {image: file} }
    Product.create(product_params.merge(images_attributes: images_attributes))
  end
end
```

In that case you have to make sure your HTML form has the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute set (otherwise only the files' filenames will get submitted, not files themselves).

Comment: Thank you very much! I've found this process frustrating enough to just switch to paperclip. I agree strongly with your blog post & the documentation is good, but if I just want things to work my fallback is paperclip. Additionally the go-rails video for jquery-file-upload seems obnoxiously long when other (older) solutions work fine and take less configuration. I would love to see a `shrine-rails` gem solution (I may look into making that myself).

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Anyway, thank you for the feedback, I will work on improving Shrine documentation around multiple file uploads.

Comment: Just wanted to update you. I did try your method and just didn't have success (I'm also using S3). Refile was very easy to implement in my rails app, so I'll stick with that until I have time to switch over later. I also am aware you're not a huge rails fan...but I believe in your blog post about shrine and would love to be an advocate.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Hehe, yeah, I'm not a huge Rails fan, but I am a fan of things being easy to set up, so that's definitely something I need to figure out here. Once documentation around multiple file uploads is improved, it will be easier for someone to create a `shrine-rails` gem.

Comment: FWIW, Rails 5 has made things a little different (I was going to say easier, but maybe ...). You can keep your polymorphic table and create the imageable relationship, but use the :optional => true switch on the polymorphic class to avoid the "parent must be created first"

Comment: I know that this is an old thread but I've been struggling with this for almost a week! This solution unfortunately does not work. param["files"] does not have all the files in the box and also  {image: file} does not work either (even when you fix the param). I don't know the answer yet... still struggling to find out.